# wlp2s0 not found? Lubuntu v16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, lubuntu

As the question says, I'm seeing an error of "wlp2s0: Device not found" when I'm trying to troubleshoot my lack of wireless connectivity.

I'm on Lubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Optiplex 755, I only rarely use Linux so I've got no idea what the next steps are and Google's not being any help for me.

Thanks for any help/pointers!

edit: the specific command I'm entering is "ip l set wlp2s0 down", as I've been trying to follow a kind of trouble-shooting thread in another forum, but I've run up against this issue and I can't find the solution.

Comment: Maybe your wireless interface is wlp3s0. Find out: `iwconfig`

Comment: Thanks! I'm seeing:
enp0s25: No wireless extension
lo: No wireless extension

Comment: Then evidently you have no wireless interface at all. I suggest that you start a new question and ask for help to get it going. I recommend that you include full diagnostics to help us: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: OK, thanks - I'll try to include as many details as possible. Unfortunately, I can't wget any of the scripts as I have no internet connection (this is a common theme in many of the fixes and diagnostic tools I've been seeing so far!), I'm guessing it's unusual to be unable to physically reach your router from your Linux machine.

Comment: Right, so in trying to get some usable and useful feedback from the OS other than "can't see it, doesn't exist", the official Ubuntu help pages lead me ultimately here: https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page
Tbh I'm just going to call this a write-off and use a competing distro, especially as Lubuntu was such a pain to set up (doesn't install bootloader unless it has an internet connection! What?!)

Comment: It is unlikely that a competing distro has the driver for your device if Ubuntu does not. I suggest that you ask the question anyway without the full diagnostics and let's see if we can help. Please include the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` ndiswrapper is almost *never* helpful.